# Android error - Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

I'm new to Android Programming. Currently following series of youtube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bzh9P1z1l90&list=PLshdtb5UWjSoLy2LPP1FsHi1hwoAS4SBi&index=7) to understand how to work with Material Design.

I've just stuck at one point now. I'm getting an error like this..

[image]

I search in google also but, didn't get any reliable answer. Here are my all files.

**styles.xml**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BhramaanTheme" parent="AppTheme"></style>

</resources>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="BhramaanTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bhramaan.android.bhramaan.LoginActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**tool_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bhramaan.android.bhramaan">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.bhramaan.android.bhramaan;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Anyone help me to understand what's I'm doing wrong at here ?

Regards

Comment: You not define ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark theme in style.xml file

Comment: @vinoth12594 : Thanks for the quick reply. Can you help me to understand how to define that one ? Shall replace this line ```<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">``` with ```<style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">``` ?

Comment: Your emulator API level???

Comment: In the preview window select your AppTheme in the top bar

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="com.bhramaan.android.bhramaan">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:supportsRtl="true" 
        android:theme="@style/BhramaanTheme"> 
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` as the themeOverlay on your Toolbar instead.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?