# Material design: Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I'm learning material design using the `Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar` theme. I'm trying to add a toolbar to my Activity following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpiIBjLzhh4&index=3&list=PLshdtb5UWjSoLy2LPP1FsHi1hwoAS4SBi).

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

v21\style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But I'm getting this `Rendering Problem`

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme
```

[image]

#### Everything I've tried so far didn't work

- Refreshing the layout.
- Updated android studio to the latest version `2.2.2` and installed everything was recommended for me in the top-right pop-ups.
- Clicking on `File>Invalidate caches/restart`.
- Changing the `API version in editor` in the preview window to `21`, `22`, `23`, `24` and `25` -I can't try preview on versions less then 21(a material design requirement/ or am I wrong???)-.
- Changed the `Theme in editor` in the preview window to a `NoActionBar` material theme and to the `AppTheme` -There's no use of changing it to `AppCompat` theme since I won't be able to view material elements like cards and so on-.
- I did also try to change it to `AppCompat`, but when I choose it from the themes list and press ok, it doesn't become the selected one; `AppTheme` becomes the selected theme for preview instead.

I tried also to add `<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>` but it gave me another warning : `Failed to find '?attr/actionBarSize' in current theme`.

What could the problem in the preview be, and how can I fix it.
Another question, as I understand until now, `AppCompat` theme doesn't contain all features of `Material` themes. Why would other people [use it to solve the problem of preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964755/4614264) or even [add a reference to it in the `v21\style.xml` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182218/4614264) instead of referencing to a `Toolbar` that exists in the `Material` themes?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: It shows me a lot of error after building the project. [Image here](http://i.imgur.com/4T5Zwxf.png).

Answer (score 0):

You have two or both styles theme with the same name.

You must change one of them to a different name, say, name="CustomTheme" or "myTheme" or whatever you want.

In the other hand, when you are learning from those tutorials always check your Android Studio Version. Things are being updated fast so find out what has changed at android Dev page or any other.